# Kickstart for installing EFI bootloader on BIOS machine

Tags: bios, centos, uefi, kickstart

Is it possible to generate [UEFI disk images](https://docs.pagure.org/koji/image_build/) from within a BIOS machine? If so, how do you make this bootloader installation with Kickstart? AFAIU `bootloader` kickstart command installs the bootloader for BIOS as it is running in a BIOS machine.

EDIT:

We are trying to build a disk image with Koji. To do so, it spawns a QEMU VM, which by default is using BIOS. Then it runs a kickstart file for configuring it. We want this configuration to allow this image to run on both BIOS and UEFI machines. Avoid having one image for each. We have seen that this is possible with https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img as it boots fine in both.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Manufacturer's supply correct BIOS files and these are what you should install.

Comment: @john I just added some extra details. This is related to https://superuser.com/questions/1524748/install-both-bios-and-uefi-bootloaders-with-kickstart but being more generic.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I do not know how to make an image with both BIOS and UEFI.